# LEGO Plastic Bag - White, Light Grey and Clear Bricks

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

[image]

I received a  sealed bag of LEGO with no instructions and I have no idea on how to build things out of it.
When I scanned the QR code on the plastic bag, it gave me a number - 617-2062 but I got no information out of it. Please help to identify the LEGO Plastic Bags as per photo attached.

Answer (score 4):

According to BrickLink, there are only two sets with both that [hinge plate](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=60471&colorID=86&in=A) and the [eyelashes](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=98138pb028&in=S) and they're quite similar: 10717 [Bricks Bricks Bricks](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10717-1) and the almost-identically-named 11717 [Bricks Bricks Plates](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=11717-1)

Comment: Despite the name, both sets have plates. BrickLink shows some variation in what wheels are in each, but I can not tell from the photo (and possibly could not tell in person) which wheels, and thus which set, you have.

Comment: I'd suggest adding set numbers to bring a little more clarity since names are similar and hard to distinguish. On topic: [10717 set doesn't have 16x16 plates that 11717 set has](https://rebrickable.com/sets/compare/slow/?1-set=10717-1&1-inv=25438&1-user_list=&2-set=11717-1&2-inv=51201&2-user_list=), which aligns perfectly with the set naming. Apart from 16x16 plates both sets are the same.

Comment: Well, no; as I'd said, their inventories show slightly different wheels. I can not speak to the accuracy of those inventories, either.